# Mysql Multiple offline databases

Tags: mysql, replication, data-synchronization

I have a web application that runs on an a main server.

The same application also runs on multiple offline servers. These offline servers are not technically offline all the times but the internet connection is unreliable.

Whenever internet becomes available at any of the offline servers, I would like to sync its data with the main server. The data syncing will be two way, changes from the main server will go to the offline server and vice versa.

I am looking at MySQL replication and it would work seamlessly if it was just one main server and one offline server, but since there can be multiple offline server, I am thinking what is the best way to proceed.

MySQL Version: 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.52, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: Which version of mysql do you have?

Comment: You can configure master-master replication with multimaster.

Comment: In multi master the solution is to add replication in a circular manner. This means that A -> B -> C -> D -> A. In this the problem is that the replication will stop if any of the nodes is down, which is a huge possibility in my case.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL replication is not what you want here.

1. MySQL replicas are read-only by default. This is for good reason.
2. MySQL replication assumes a linear "timeline". There is no provision for merging changes from multiple sources; even if you set a replica as writable while it was split from the master, it would be unable to continue replicating changes from the master afterwards, as its data would have diverged from the master, and it has no way to reconcile changes.

You will need to implement a synchronization scheme in your application. Note that this may be complicated -- you will need to consider cases where changes have been made to an object by both "sides" of a split.